What are the natural words/phrases that native speakers use when they want to elaborate on what they’re talking but haven’t thought of anything else?
For example, when talking about global warming and the causes leading to the problem, suddenly I run out of ideas to talk about (not because I can’t find the exact words to express what I want to say, but I’m brainstorming ideas). I often use these expressions in this case:

Let me see …
Let me see what else…

What are other (more) natural ways to use in this situation?

Your answers are fine.  "what else..."  "let me think..."  "hmm..."   "there are probably more reasons... (for global warming)"   "let's see..."

The problem with this question is you are asking "how do I talk badly, like native speakers sometimes talk badly".  But you can't practice being bad at English!  You can't get better at English by being better at copying the failures at speaking English by native speakers.

I don't know that any words are needed! Advice on public speaking and writing often says to avoid "fillers" like "Um," "er," etc. If there's nothing left to say, say nothing!
But if you're being collaborative, and just because you've run out of ideas doesn't mean others have, you can invite their input. "That's all I can think of; how about you?"
